# VBA Select & Copy ignores first row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code I could use some help on. This script I wrote is meant to copy a range from the first row to the last row to another sheet. It works perfectly if there are more than 2 rows containing data, but if there is only 1 row (the first row), it ignores that data, does not copy it, and outputs an error.

Is there anything you can identify that might fix this code? I've searched endlessly with no results. Thanks!

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Worksheets("HCA")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("FormA")
Set ws3 = Worksheets("NamedRange")

ws3.Range("T1:U1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("FormA").Select
ws2.Range("AQ7").PasteSpecial
```

Comment: Do you need just the values of the data you're copying? Or do you want the format/formula/etc?

Comment: Values of data. Callum's answer solved my issue perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`End(xlDown)` will have undesirable effects when there is only one row being used. It's much more reliable to use `xlUp` from the bottom of your worksheet instead

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim ws3 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("HCA")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("FormA")
    Set ws3 = Worksheets("NamedRange")

    With ws3
        .Range(.Range("T1"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp)).Copy
    End With
    ws2.Range("AQ7").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Comment: @Wxby - If you just need values, you can skip `.Copy` altogether and just do `ws2.Range("AQ7").Value = ws3.Range(ws3.Range("T1"),ws3.Cells(ws3.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Value`.

Comment: @BruceWayne, what if the copy range is more than one cell? I think it's a bit more complicated than that, but I don't disagree that ideally the code would be redesigned to use `.Value` instead

Comment: @CallumDA if the copy range is more than one cell, you can just make the destination range just as big.

Answer (score 3):

Replace,

```
ws3.Range("T1:U1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
```

... with,

```
with ws3
    .Range(.cells(1, "T"), .cells(.rows.count, "U").end(xlup)).copy
end with
```

When looking for the last non-blank cell, look from the bottom up; not from the top down.